# How to maintain sequential jquery method call?

Tags: jquery

I have a three level jstree.After making all selection I am invoking displayCount() method to show the proper search results count based on the selection. Now when I uncheck one selection,It thoroughly check all nodes to maintain proper selected structure and then it should invoke displayCount() method. But issue is that it already called displayCount() method before unchecking nodes.SO I am getting wrong counts. Sequence of method call is as follows:-

```
      UnchekSelectedNodes(){
          // nodes are getting unchecked depends on parent-child relation.
          // purely DOM structure update operation. 
       }

      displayCount(){
         // ajax call to show proper count based on selected nodes/checkboxes
      }

      checkForEmptyDiv(){
         // if it becomes no selected hide the div.
      }
```

Issue is..always displayCOunt() gets called before completion of UnchekSelectedNodes() operation.I tried with method chainng depending on flag.It does not work.

Any Solution??

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax see `async`

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do it in a setTimeout...

When I´m lazy and things happens in wrong order, i just add a setTimeout with a timeout of 1, then all other calls are called and my timeout after that.

```
UnchekSelectedNodes(){
          // nodes are getting unchecked depends on parent-child relation.
          // purely DOM structure update operation. 
       }

      displayCount(){
         setTimeout(function() {
            //just do what ever you want.
         }, 1);
      }

      checkForEmptyDiv(){
         // if it becomes no selected hide the div.
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Luke for your quick reply..can you please elaborate with simple snippet..it would be great help for me.

Comment: see update. if I understood your question correctly, this will help you.